# NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindow.scroll]

Tags: javascript, event-handling, scroll

```
try{
window.parent.document.body.onscroll = scroll;

function scroll(){
   cs_flag.isScrolled=1;
   console.log(getResult());
}
}
catch(e){
document.body.onscroll = scroll;

function scroll(){
   cs_flag.isScrolled=1;
   console.log(getResult());
}

}
```

The problem is scroll event handler is giving out these exceptions
NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindow.scroll] and hence on scroll the isScrolled is not setting to 1.Please help.

Thanks in adavance

Comment: why the try catch and why are you defining scroll twice?

Comment: @epascarello the try catch is for taking care of Cross Domain Iframes.If it is not cross domain try would execute the handler in parents document.body.If it is cross domain then catch would execute the handler in Iframe's document.body.Yes I will take the function out and just call the function inside try and catch.Thanks.

Comment: Can you point me to where the problem is.